# How to show multiple image with button click

Tags: javascript

All I'm trying to do is get 20 images (all the same image with the same class name) to appear on the click of a single 'button' (the 'button' is actually a div). I tried trying to hide the 'tick' image themselves and that was a no go, so decided to put the image inside a div, still nothing.

I have searched Stack Overflow for solutions, which I've found a couple of similar things, but nothing does what I need it to.

The Button

```
<div id="reveal" onclick="displayTicks()"><a href="#" class="home-link link-1"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a><br><br>Reveal Answers</div>
```

CSS

```
.tick, .tick > img{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: auto;
}
.tick{
    display: none;
}
```

JS example question with 'tick' in the correct answer

```
{
      question: "How many different ways are there to commit a Quidditch foul?",
      answers: {
          a: "50",
          b: "150",
          c: "350",
          d: "700<div class='tick'><img src='https://i.ibb.co/v43bTPs/tick.png'></div>"
      },
      correctAnswer: 'd'
    },
```

JS

```
function displayTicks(){
  const divArray = 
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('tick'));
  const displayStyle = divArray[0].display.style === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
divArray.forEach(div => {
div.style.display = displayStyle;
}); 
}
```

I can get them all appear (or not) via the CSS, but I just want to toggle it with the 'reveal' button.

Comment: Did you misspell `onclik`?  Shouldn't it be `onclick`?

Comment: Thank's for pointing out the typo! Fixed that, but still not working.

Comment: Can you add example on how the complete HTML looks like? In combination with your div that should be a button?

Comment: full html: https://github.com/DeannaCarina/HarryPotterQuiz/blob/master/quiz-pages/book1.html

full JS https://github.com/DeannaCarina/HarryPotterQuiz/blob/master/assets/js/book1Script.js

Comment: Your problem is here `divArray[0].display.style === 'none'`... It should be `divArray[0].style.display=== 'none'`

Comment: `style.display` not `display.style`

Comment: @AdityaParab Thank you so much!! Something so simple and I couldn't see it, works perfectly now, thank you!

Comment: No worries... If you stare at the code for a long time, everything starts looking the same.. Helps to have extra pair of eyes...

Answer (score 0):

the mistake is in this line:

```
const displayStyle = divArray[0].display.style === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
```

it should be like this:

```
const displayStyle = divArray[0].style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
```